# get gtk theme css property from python Gtk3

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, gtk3, gnome

I am having trouble in getting certain properties from the system Gtk3 theme css (gtk.css) to render contextual components in my python Gtk3 application.

What I have from my system theme gtk.css are the following:

```
entry {
  ...
  color: #5c616c;
  border-color: #cfd6e6;
  background-color: #ffffff; }
  entry:focus {
    background-clip: border-box;
    color: #5c616c;
    border-color: #5294e2;
    background-color: #ffffff; }
  entry:disabled {
    color: rgba(92, 97, 108, 0.55);
    border-color: rgba(207, 214, 230, 0.55);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55); }
  entry.warning {
    color: white;
    border-color: #F27835;
    background-color: #f7ae86; }
    entry.warning image {
      color: white; }
...
```

What I would like to get from it are those contextual colors, e.g. `background-color` from `entry.warning`, etc.

I have done some research and here is where I get stuck:

```
css_provider = Gtk.CssProvider.get_default()
warning_color = css_provider.get_style(something to put here)
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The correct way would be to modify a `Gtk.Widget`'s `Gtk.StyleContext` so that the CSS rule applies to it, then use the `Gtk.render_whatever()` functions to draw your contextual components.

For example to render a background with the same style as the `warning` background on a `Gtk.Entry` subclass:

```
context = my_entry.get_style_context()
context.save()
context.add_class('warning')
Gtk.render_background(context, blah, blah, blah)
context.restore()
```

Note that it's not possible to get the background *color* directly from CSS. A CSS background may be a color, or an image, or a gradient.

Comment: Thank you very much. My follow up question would be that I want to use the contextual color as text color (tag) in a textview widget, and it's not necessary that I have an actual entry object.

Comment: Like I said, you can't reliably get the background color because there may be no such thing as a "background color" for a particular widget. There are some styles you can get by using `context.get_property()`.